# How to focus of tab from one element to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form in which the following is one of the tables

```
<tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td valign="top"><nobr> Address Line 1 :</nobr></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="strLine1" class="textfield" id="strLine1" onFocus="nextfield ='strLine2';" />
<br /><span id="strLine1Info" ></span>              
   </td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td align="left" valign="top"><nobr>Address Line 1 :</nobr></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="hstrLine1" class="textfield" id="hstrLine1" onFocus="nextfield ='hstrLine2';" />
    <br /><span id="hstrLine1Info" ></span>             
   </td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td valign="top"><nobr>Address Line 2 :</nobr></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="strLine2" class="textfield" id="strLine2" onFocus="nextfield ='city';" />
    <br /><span id="strLine2Info" ></span>              
   </td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td align="left" valign="top"><nobr>Address Line 2 :</nobr></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="hstrLine2" class="textfield" id="hstrLine2" onFocus="nextfield ='hcity';" />
    <br /><span id="hstrLine2Info" ></span>             
   </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td valign="top"> State :</td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" name="state" class="textfield" value="Secrete" id="state"  onFocus="nextfield ='Zip';" disabled />
    <br /><span id="stateInfo" ></span>                         </td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td valign="top"> State :</td>
     <td>
<input type="text" name="hstate" class="textfield" value="Secrete" id="hstate" onFocus="nextfield ='hZip';" disabled />
<br /><span id="hstateInfo" ></span>                            </td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
```

I want to move the tab (keyboard tab) from

```
Address Line 1 -> 
Address Line 2 -> 
State -> (second column)
Address Line 1 -> (second column)
Address Line 2 -> (second column)State
```

I want to do this in jQuery.

Comment: How on earth is this related to PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `tabindex` property for each element one after another.  For the first column's tab index in sequence, and for the second column's tab index in sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just set the tabindex value on each form element in the order?